# Failed to connect to SMTP using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have tried to connect using SMTP, but failed. Here is my code.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 20;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN';
    $mail->Username = 'david_thedragonzzz@yahoo.com';
    $mail->Password = 'secret';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->setFrom('david_thedragonzzz@yahoo.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('david_thedragonzzz@yahoo.com', 'User');
    $mail->addReplyTo('test@yahoo.com', 'Information');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

The result

```
2018-02-07 10:45:43 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2018-02-07 10:45:43 Connection: opened
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SMTP INBOUND: "220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready"
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
2018-02-07 10:45:43 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SMTP INBOUND: "250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 41697280"
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8 BITMIME"
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SMTP INBOUND: "250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 XYMCOOKIE OAUTHBEARER"
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 41697280250-8 BITMIME250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 XYMCOOKIE OAUTHBEARER
2018-02-07 10:45:43 Auth method requested: LOGIN
2018-02-07 10:45:43 Auth methods available on the server: PLAIN,LOGIN,XOAUTH2,XYMCOOKIE,OAUTHBEARER
2018-02-07 10:45:43 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SMTP INBOUND: "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2018-02-07 10:45:43 CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx==
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SMTP INBOUND: "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
2018-02-07 10:45:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2018-02-07 10:45:43 CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx==
2018-02-07 10:45:46 SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.0 (#MBR1212) Incorrect username or password."
2018-02-07 10:45:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.0 (#MBR1212) Incorrect username or password.
2018-02-07 10:45:46 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.0 (#MBR1212) Incorrect username or password.
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2018-02-07 10:45:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-02-07 10:45:46 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Bye"
2018-02-07 10:45:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
2018-02-07 10:45:46 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

I can't understand how come this code gives me "incorrect username or password" error. I have configured smtp using Mozilla Thunderbird. Username and Password is right, but still gives me this kind of error.

Comment: Does it help if you change it to `$mail->AuthType = 'PLAIN';`? Also, there is no such debug level as 20; 2 is enough for this problem.

Comment: BTW your debug output contained decodable ID and password (which I edited out), but you may want to change them.

Comment: PLAIN doesn't work

Comment: This seems to be a [common Yahoo problem](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&filter=location&location=category:english&q=MBR1212) with various possible solutions, including a "use less secure apps" gmail-style option.